# SQL Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have below table structure in MS SQL

```
AirQuoteID        Name        SalesValue
7                  M          49.50
7                  N          23.10
7                 +45         233.20
7                 +100        233.20
7                 +250        2333.10
```

I want a query which can return

```
AirQuoteID      M        N        +45        +100    +250
7               49.50    23.10    233.20     233.20   2333.10
```

What will be the optimum solution. The Values are dynamic

Comment: Also refer this
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10840/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) operator.

```
;With T As
(
SELECT 7 AirQuoteID,'M' Name,49.50 SalesValue UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AirQuoteID,'N', 23.10 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AirQuoteID,'+45',233.20 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AirQuoteID,'+100',233.20 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AirQuoteID,'+250',2333.10
)
SELECT AirQuoteID, [M], [N], [+45], [+100], [+250] 
FROM T
PIVOT
(
MAX(SalesValue)
FOR Name IN ([M], [N], [+45], [+100], [+250])
) AS pvt;
```

However if the values for the columns are not fixed you will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-cross-tabs-pivot-tables).

Comment: thanx for the link, the values are dynamic. wil check and try to implement looking at the link

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-cross-tabs-pivot-tables really helped with small work around

Answer (score 0):

As the data is dynamic, pivot wont help

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-cross-tabs-pivot-tables link posted by @Martin really helped.

first create the below procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[crosstab] 
@select varchar(8000),
@sumfunc varchar(100), 
@pivot varchar(100), 
@table varchar(100) 
AS

DECLARE @sql varchar(8000), @delim varchar(1)
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

print ('SELECT ' + @pivot + ' AS [pivot] INTO ##pivot FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE 1=2')
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @pivot + ' AS [pivot] INTO ##pivot FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE 1=2')
EXEC ('INSERT INTO ##pivot SELECT DISTINCT ' + @pivot + ' FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE ' 
+ @pivot + ' Is Not Null')

SELECT @sql='',  @sumfunc=stuff(@sumfunc, len(@sumfunc), 1, ' END)' )

SELECT @delim=CASE Sign( CharIndex('char', data_type)+CharIndex('date', data_type) ) 
WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '''' END 
FROM tempdb.information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='##pivot' AND column_name='pivot'

SELECT @sql=@sql + '''' + convert(varchar(100), [pivot]) + ''' = ' + 
stuff(@sumfunc,charindex( '(', @sumfunc )+1, 0, ' CASE ' + @pivot + ' WHEN ' 
+ @delim + convert(varchar(100), [pivot]) + @delim + ' THEN ' ) + ', ' FROM ##pivot

DROP TABLE ##pivot

SELECT @sql=left(@sql, len(@sql)-1)
SELECT @select=stuff(@select, charindex(' FROM ', @select)+1, 0, ', ' + @sql + ' ')

EXEC (@select)
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
GO
```

The article didnt mention to retrieve data from same table, so below is how you do it

```
EXECUTE crosstab 'select titles.AirQuoteID from AirSaleQuoteRateSlab titles 
                    inner join 
                    (select distinct AirQuoteID,[Name] from AirSaleQuoteRateSlab) sales 
                    on (sales.AirQuoteID=titles.AirQuoteID) 
                    group by titles.AirQuoteID', 'AVG(titles.SalesValue)','titles.Name','AirSaleQuoteRateSlab titles'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select AirQuoteID,
sum(case Name when 'M' then SalesValue else 0 end) 'M',
sum(case Name when 'N' then SalesValue else 0 end) 'N',
sum(case Name when '+45' then SalesValue else 0 end) '+45',
sum(case Name when '+100' then SalesValue else 0 end) '+100',
sum(case Name when '+250' then SalesValue else 0 end) '+250'
from Table1
group by AirQuoteID
```

Comment: The data and columns will be dynamic so this wont help

Comment: @Aamod: In your question you said "The Values are dynamic" which seemed like SalesValues are dynamic. Hence my answer.
Later when I read the comments below then it revealed that everything is dynamic. any way.